# what does "$" mean in this SSI conditional statement?

Tags: ssi, using-directives, dollar-sign

I was reading about SSI [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes).  The first code example under the section **Control Directives** looks like this:

```
<!--#if expr="${Sec_Nav}" -->
<!--#include virtual="" -->
<!--#endif -->
```

What does the "$" sign mean?  EOF, a function, get...???

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a way to inject a variable value inside a string

```
<!--#if expr="${Sec_Nav}" -->
```

this is comparing **expr** to the value of **Sec_Nav**

Comment: "_It is just a way to inject a variable value inside a string_" so does this mean it is not needed?  It could have been written as `<!--#if expr="{Sec_Nav}" -->`

Comment: @Chris22 '<!--#if expr="{Sec_Nav}" -->' compares expr to "{Sec_Env}" while '<!--#if expr="${Sec_Nav}" -->' compares expr to the value of Sec_Env